# Combined COUNTIF for several columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

We have a table with values like this:

[image]

I need a formula for cell `D1` to count rows that have in column `A` value "one" and column B is not empty. For example:

- in first row `A1==one` but `B1` is empty; (that doesn't count)
- in second row `A2==one` and `B2` is not empty; (that counts 1)
- ...
- in 4th row `A4` is not equal to value "one" (that doesn't count)

I know about formulas like `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` but I can`t figure out how to use them with combined condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"one",B:B,"<>")
```

Comment: Cool. It worked! I thought that COUNTIFS will produce sum of the counts by each listed condition. But it does exactly what I need - logical AND on conditions.